# React useDispatch How to keep my search conditions

Tags: reactjs

How to keep my search conditions.

a.js page

```
const search = {
      year_month: select_year,
      company: select_company,
}; 

dispatch(GetAllData(search));
```

b.js page

```
export const GetAllData = createAsyncThunk('DispatchAccountingApp', async (search, { dispatch }) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/api/', { ...search });
    const data = await response.data;
    return { data };
});
```

How can I keep the search conditions until my next update !

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your search object should be in the state and you should read from the state and perform a search.

```
// this should be in the app state
const search = {
      year_month: select_year,
      company: select_company,
};
```

You can also keep one more flag `searchOn` which should be used to keep track whether search is being performed or not.

if you dont have some sort of storage like state then the only way is to keep in local-storage\session-storage of browser till your next update. And when next searh is performed then you need to update the storage values also

Since you are using react js, you would prefer app state than storage to do this.